# I need to fecth selected data from a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Sample file

```
ABCD|XYZ_123
CDEF|XYZ_456
GHIJ|ZEE_569
```

Output:

```
XYZ_123
XYZ_456
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to better help you solve your problem, please indicate what operating system and/or base tools (including, but not limited to, which shell) you have at your disposal, and what you have already tried to solve the problem. Also, it appears you not only want to extract all text behind the `|`, but also filter out specific values of the preceding "key" (e.g. NOT `GHIJ`). Please edit your question to include the full requirements of the solution.

Comment: Can you also have `fooXYZ_123`? Should that be found? Or should the `XYZ` be immediately after a `|`? Will it always be the second field (where fields are defined as `|`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options:

1. Grep and cut: `grep XYZ file | cut -d'|' -f2`
2. (GNU) Grep only: `grep -o 'XYZ.*$' file`
3. Awk: `awk -F'|' '/XYZ/{print $2}' file`
4. Bash array and loop (just because I can):

---

```
declare -A array
eval array=( $(printf '[%s]=%s ' $(tr '|' ' ' < file)) )
for v in ${array[@]}
do 
     [[ $v =~ XYZ ]] && echo $v
done
```